# Python list to bitwise operations

Tags: python, django, bitwise-operators

Is there a way to take a list of django query expresses (e.g. `Q(first_name="Jordan")`, where `Q` is `django.db.models.Q`) and bitwise OR them together?

In other words, I have something like this:

```
search_string = "various search terms"
```

And I want to do this:

```
search_params = [Q(description__icontains=term) for term in re.split(r'\W', search_string)]
search_params = something_magical(search_params)
results = Record.objects.filter(search_params)
```

where `search_params` now is equivalent to `Q(description__icontains="various") | Q(description__icontains="search" | Q(description__icontains="terms"`

I know it would be possible with a function like this:

```
def something_magical(lst):
    result = lst[0]
    for l in lst[1:]
        result |= l
    return result
```

So I'm wondering if this functionality is already built into Python (and I'm assuming it's more optimized than my function here).

Although I'm interested in it for this application, I'm also just interested in it theoretically.

Comment: I don't think there is such an django operator...But you could just do all the "or" queries and then use python set operators to combine the results ? ( http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#set-objects )

Comment: @RichardGreen that can create pretty ugly queries

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You probably want

```
import operator 
from functools import reduce    # Python 3
search_params = reduce(operator.or_, search_params, Q())
```

This will place a bit-wise or (`|`) between all the items in `search_params`, starting with an empty condition `Q()`.

Comment: Nice! Things like this make my love python more and more.

Comment: Just spent a little while playing with `reduce` and `map`.

Comment: Great you like it! You'll probably also enjoy [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) then.

Comment: Very smart. Did not know about operators as functions.