# Perform a logical exclusive OR on a Django Q object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-q

I would like to perform a logical exclusive OR ([XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_disjunction)) on `django.db.models.Q` objects, using [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module to limit the choices of a model field to a subset of foreignkey. I am doing this in Django 1.4.3 along with Python 2.7.2. I had something like this:

```
import operator

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

def query_group_lkup(group_name):
    return Q(user__user__groups__name__exact=group_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
                 User,
                 verbose_name=_("Author"),
                 null=False,
                 default='',
                 related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_author",
                 # This would have provide an exclusive OR on the selected group name for User
                 limit_choices_to=reduce(
                     operator.xor,
                     map(query_group_lkup, getattr(settings, 'AUTHORIZED_AUTHORS', ''))
                 )
```

`AUTHORIZED_AUTHORS` is a list of existing group names.

But this did not work, because `Q` objects do not support `^` operator (only `|` and `&` operators from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)). The message from the stacktrace was (partly) the following:

```
File "/home/moi/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/moi/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/home/moi/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/dvpt/toto/apps/book/models.py", line 42, in <module>
    class Book(models.Model):
  File "/opt/dvpt/toto/apps/book/models.py", line 100, in Book
    map(query_group_lkup, getattr(settings, 'AUTHORIZED_AUTHORS', ''))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'Q' and 'Q'
```

Therefore, inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903128/python-list-to-bitwise-operations) I attempted to implement an XOR for my specific lookup. It is not really flexible as the lookup is hardcoded (I would need to use `kwargs` in the arguments of `query_xor` for example...). I ended up doing something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.query import EmptyQuerySet
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

def query_xor_group(names_group):
    """Get a XOR of the queries that match the group names in names_group."""

    if not len(names_group):
        return EmptyQuerySet()
    elif len(names_group) == 1:
        return Q(user__user__groups__name__exact=names_group[0])

    q_chain_or = Q(user__user__groups__name__exact=names_group[0])
    q_chain_and = Q(user__user__groups__name__exact=names_group[0])

    for name in names_group[1:]:
        query = Q(user__user__groups__name__exact=name)
        q_chain_or |= query
        q_chain_and &= query

    return q_chain_or & ~q_chain_and

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
                 User,
                 verbose_name=_("author"),
                 null=False,
                 default='',
                 related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_author",
                 # This provides an exclusive OR on the SELECT group name for User
                 limit_choices_to=query_xor_group(getattr(settings, 'AUTHORIZED_AUTHORS', ''))
                 )
```

It works as I want but I seems to me rather not pythonic (especially the `query_xor_group` method).
Would there be a better (more direct way) of doing this?

Basically, my question can be stripped of the `limit_choices_to` part and be summarized as:

**How can I make a bitwise exclusive OR on a set of `django.db.models.Q` objects in a Djangonic way?**

Comment: For future readers: It looks like XOR is going to be implemented in Django 4.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#xor and the code: https://github.com/django/django/commit/c6b4d62fa2c7f73b87f6ae7e8cf1d64ee5312dc5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could add an `__xor__()` method to Q that uses and/or/not to do the XOR logic.

```
from django.db.models import Q

class QQ:
    def __xor__(self, other):    
        not_self = self.clone()
        not_other = other.clone()
        not_self.negate()
        not_other.negate()

        x = self & not_other
        y = not_self & other

        return x | y

Q.__bases__ += (QQ, )
```

After doing this I was able to `Q(...) ^ Q(...)` in a `filter()` call.

```
Foobar.objects.filter(Q(blah=1) ^ Q(bar=2))
```

Which means the original attempt no longer throws an unsupported operand exception.

```
limit_choices_to=reduce(
                     operator.xor,
                     map(query_group_lkup, getattr(settings, 'AUTHORIZED_AUTHORS', ''))
                 )
```

Tested in `Django 1.6.1` on `Python 2.7.5`

Comment: @Dan R: Could you please elaborate on your solution with full example?

Comment: Adding that class just makes the askers first attempt work but I also included how you'd use it in any filter call.

Comment: While this certainly works, I think it's best to avoid monkeypatching like this in python, since it is now quite hard to track when this patch is applied (although, I suppose you could just see if `QQ` is in `Q.mro()`).  IMO, it would be better to subclass `Q` with `QQ` and use that instead; you can use the subclass globally if that makes things more consistent.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, you should definitely initiate a pull request for this into django.

Comment: @astex this has been included in Django recently

Answer (score 13):

[Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/#models) added support for XOR:

> `Q` objects and querysets can now be combined using `^` as the exclusive or (`XOR`) operator. `XOR` is natively supported on MariaDB and MySQL. For databases that do not support `XOR`, the query will be converted to an equivalent using `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT`.

It means you can now write `Foobar.objects.filter(Q(blah=1) ^ Q(bar=2))` without monkey patching.
It was worth waiting nine years, wasn't it?