# Filtering out the Users if Conversation occurred

Tags: python, django

Here's my Model

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    msg_content = models.TextField()
```

How can I filter out the Users only if, either Current User have sent them a message or they have sent Current User a message, as we see on our Social Networks?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) in combination with the [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object, which allows you to make more complex queries (in your case, an **OR** expression):

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> user = request.user  # Take the current user
>>> Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=user) | Q(receiver=user))  # Filter messages where the sender or the receiver is the current user
<QuerySet [...]>
```

Comment: Sir, I have even used .distinct() but why it's filtering out the user equal number times as the number of messages sent ?

Comment: @ShivamKumarDodval I think you should use `.distinct('sender')`.

Comment: Sir, it's raising an error "NotImplementedError at /messages/, 
DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend". I'm currently using sqlite3.

Comment: @ShivamKumarDodval Then I think you should perform and **exclusive OR**, not **OR**. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711203/perform-a-logical-exclusive-or-on-a-django-q-object

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :
1. user_obj = User.objects.filter(sender__receiver__pk= request.user.id) 
2. users = User.objects.filter(sender__receiver= request.user)