# How to optimize django query filter?

Tags: django, database

Basically I have this url dispatcher that capture a search term with each word separated by + to be search in the query. I have done this this is works but I think this will hit the performance due to repeated search to the database. Is there a better way to do this?

```
def search(request, **kwargs):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    test = {}
    result = BlogPage.objects.select_related('ImageMedia')

    if 'search_content' in kwargs:
        test['search_content'] = kwargs['search_content']
        if kwargs['search_content'] != '0':
            search_words = kwargs['search_content'].split('+')
            for words in search_words:
                result = result.filter(content__icontains=words)

    context_dict = {'blog_list': result}

    return render_to_response('blog/blog_search.html', context_dict, context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pre-build your filter, like (untested):

```
from django.db import Q    
search_content = kwargs.get('search_content', '')
myfilter = Q()

for term in search_content.split('+'):
    myfilter |= Q(content__icontains=term)

result = BlogPage.objects.filter(myfilter).select_related('ImageMedia')
```

Comment: It gives me this error. unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'str' and 'Q'

Comment: This is because you have to preset myfilter first, e.g. myfilter=Q()

Answer (score 0):

I think [Python list to bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903128/python-list-to-bitwise-operations) is simpler when you are using python 2.7

PS: <del>`reduce()` function has been removed in Python 3, so you can't use it and it is no compatibility</del>.`reduce()` has been move into module `functools`